How to get Digital Clock in MUI DateTimePicker?
I am using MUI's DateTimePicker , and for time selection i am getting an analog clock. Is there a way through which i can get the digital clock.
I took help of chatGPT but, it didnt provided me a working solution. There was a Answer available on StackOverflow, but that also didnt work.
My code looks like this
views = ['day', 'hours', 'minutes'],

<DateTimePicker
   label='Start Date'
   value={new Date(selectedDateTime.startTime)}
   views={views}
   minDate={minDate}
   maxDateTime={dayjs(new Date())}
   onChange={handleStartDateChange}
   renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
 />


Seems like this is what you want:
<DemoItem label="Desktop variant">
    <DesktopDateTimePicker defaultValue={dayjs('2022-04-17T15:30')} />
</DemoItem>

Read documentation here:
https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-time-picker/#available-components
